# Java JPA/SAX Handler Events/for loop Not Running

Tags: java, xml, jpa, for-loop, xml-parsing

I have 7,464 `siteID` Integers stored in a `List` with the same name (`siteID`). I am looping through the List and using each `siteID` Integer to query an SQL table with `JPA` to return a `SiteTable` instance and get its `postcode` String.

I am then using those `postcode` Strings to check XML files to retrieve latitude and longitude values against each `postcode`. Below is the loop;

```
for (Integer id : siteID){           
                siteTable = em.find(SiteTable.class, id);
                XMLPositionRetriever.runXMLQuery(siteTable.getPostcode());         
        }
```

That postcode String is then put into the `runXMLQuery(String toFind)` method in the class below;

```
public class XMLPositionRetriever extends DefaultHandler{

String postcodeToFind;
boolean found = false;

public XMLPositionRetriever(){
}

public XMLPositionRetriever(String toFind){
    postcodeToFind = toFind;
}

public static void runXMLQuery(String toFind){

    try {      
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser(); 
        XMLPositionRetriever handler = new XMLPositionRetriever(toFind);
        saxParser.parse("src\\haldata\\postcodes"+toFind.charAt(0)+".xml", handler);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

@Override 
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (postcodeToFind.equals(attributes.getValue("postcode"))){
        System.out.println("The postcode '"+postcodeToFind+"', has a latitude of "+attributes.getValue("latitude")+" and a longitude of "+attributes.getValue("longitude"));
        found = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endDocument(){
    if(!found){
    System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
}

}
```

The event handlers above make sure that something is always outputted even if the `postcode` is not found in any of the XML files, or even if there is an exception. So, what I would expect is for the code above to `println` 7464 times, but instead I am getting 50 or so lines outputted. It *appears* that the loop isn't actually running for each `siteID`, but the code says it should be. I've narrowed the problem down to the code I've shown above (most likely within the loop itself) but now I can't see anything wrong. Any suggestions?

The XMLs look like this, but with up to 300,000 entry elements;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<postcodes>
    <entry postcode='AB1 0AA' latitude='7.101478' longitude='2.242852' />
</postcodes>
```

Sorry to dump so much code on you all, but I don't think I could give you a complete picture with less.

Comment: Update: Testing `siteID.size()` on the List immediately before running the for loop shows 7,464. The loop however, is only running 56 times (I added a print statement to show every loop cycle). So the problem appears to be in the loop itself.

Comment: Wild guessing: Does `em.find(SiteTable.class, id);` throw an exception?

Comment: Double post, thanks to edit "timeout" - Another wild guess: Did you try catching `Throwable` instead of `Exception` in `runXMLQuery`?

Comment: Apparently EntityManager.find can throw an IllegalArgumentException. I'll have to check if that's the case, but judging by the criteria for throwing that exception I can't see why it would in this case. I'll have to check when I get into work tomorrow. What difference would catching Throwable make? I am ashamed to say my knowledge is terrible when it comes to exceptions etc.

Comment: `Exception` extends `Throwable` - and so does Error, so MAYBE you don't catch the error causing the loop to break. I don't see any other way the loop could break too early.

Comment: That makes sense. I have two anomalies now. I changed the catch statement to catch Throwable, but there is no change. The other anomaly is that the runXMLQuery method is throwing the occassional nullpointer exception, except I have used lots and lots of `if(x != null){}` statements to prevent any null pointers getting that far, but it's still finding them somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs (below, commented);

```
for (Integer id : siteID){           
            siteTable = em.find(SiteTable.class, id);
            XMLPositionRetriever.runXMLQuery(siteTable.getPostcode());// <--- Null point exception on this line.       
    }
```

Where `em.find()` did not find an `Entity` class, it returned null. In such cases `siteTable.getPostcode()` was throwing the `NullPointerException`. So, I added in an if statement to prevent a null reference going through to that statement (as well as adding in some other conditions to tidy up the XML search).

```
for (Integer id : siteID){ 
       site = em.find(SiteTable.class, id);
       if(site != null && site.getPostcode() != null && !site.getPostcode().equals("")){
           XMLPositionRetriever.runXMLQuery(site.getPostcode()); 
       }
          else{
           System.out.println("The site and/or postcode against this Instruction does not exist.");
       }
}
```

Thank you to MarioP, without whom I probably wouldn't have figured it out.